# csv.reader () - How can I extract columns from a csv.reader object?

Tags: python, csv

I have the following records below in a csv file and need to be able to access specific columns in order to extract, set and compare relationships. How would I go about doing this? I've tried list() and next(), but no luck so far.

For example: I'd like to extract the entire "last_name" column.

```
first_name  last_name   company_name
James Butt Benton, John B Jr
Josephine Darakjy Chanay, Jeffrey A Esq
Art Venere  Chemel, James L Cpa
Lenna   Paprocki    Feltz Printing Service

   import csv

   f= open('us-500.csv', 'rU')
   reader = (csv.reader(f))                 # use list or next
   phone_number = []
   for row in reader:
        # phone_number.append
        print row

   f.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert a csv file to a list for future processing, just pass the reader to the list constructor. In cpython, you can make it a one-liner:

```
my_list = list(csv.reader(open('us-500.csv', 'rU')))
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `for` loop try `last_name = row[1]`.